# What is the ideal state of symbiotic balance in soil called?

Tags: soil, organic, terminology

I have been looking into organic gardening recently and I remember seeing something that I found very interesting. It had to do with the soil being in perfect balance with bacteria, insects, and the like living in a symbiotic relationship that helps plants thrive. The soil was said to be in a "***something*** state" if I remember correctly. Does anyone know the name?

Comment: You might have heard it called a biodynamic state but thats a loaded term that can mean a lot of things - some of which are pseudoscience.

Comment: I don't think that was the term that I had come across. And just to note, I don't mind if the idea is unsubstantiated by science. I am willing to do research on the topic myself and do some "mad-sciencing" through experimentation.

Answer (score 2):

'Perfect ecological balance' is the term usually used - bit of a misnomer really, because even if the symbiotic and ecological processes are 'perfect' at one point, they will fluctuate and alter over time. The basis of organic gardening (other than the non use of pesticides/herbicides and chemical feeds) is that you put back into the soil what's been taken out by adding composted, humus rich materials frequently. These 'inoculate' exhausted soils and encourage a good diversity of bacteria, fungal spores and micro bio diversity generally, all of which enables plants to grow well, without the need to add chemical feeds.